# Using parametrized modules on manifests

Tags: puppet

I'm having some trouble using parameters on puppet modules, here is what I'm doing:

#### init.pp

```
node "example_node.example_domain" {
       
 include repositories("TESTS")

}
```

#### manifest of repositories module

```
class repositories($repository) {
    
notify{"The repository is: ${repository}": }    

}
```

Then the result is:

Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Unknown function repositories at /etc/puppet/environments/test/manifests/init.pp:2 on node example_node.example_domain

What am I doing wrong? All I want is to pass a parameter to a module because each server will have its own invocation to this module and their particular parameter.

Thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [the fine manual](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#declaring-classes) that explains how "Include-like behavior relies on external data and defaults for class parameter values".
If you have to pass parameters then use the Resource-like declaration:

```
repositories{ 'some_name':
  repository => 'TESTS'
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm looking something similar to:

include repositories("TESTS")

and then another server re-use the same module like:

include repositories("PRO")

and then another like:

include repositories("PRO2")

Comment: The syntax you keep trying to use is *wrong*.  Puppet resources and classes are instantiated with arguments in the manner that this answer demonstrates.

Comment: Ok, I get it, but how can you pass the parameter through the init.pp manifest file?